# Linking fails with CMake, DSO-Link-Change

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, cmake, ld

My software that compiled fine on linux a few months ago stopped compiling on my new ubuntu:

```
Linking CXX executable myApp
/usr/bin/ld: ../libMyLib/libMyLib.a(MyFile.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6resizeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayENS_5Size_IiEEddi'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '_ZN2cv6resizeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayENS_5Size_IiEEddi' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [myApp/myApp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [myApp/CMakeFiles/myApp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I guess it's related to https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/UnderstandingDSOLinkChange.

My project (all cmake) contains several libraries and an application, both the libraries and the application depend on opencv and/or boost (each on some different ones). My own libraries are built as .a files, ocv/boost are pulled in as shared libraries, and the linking of the application then fails with above error.

I also tried to build my own libraries as SHARED but that resulted in even more errors. The CMakeLists of my libraries look like

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED core)
...stuff...
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_library( ${SUBPROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE} ${HEADERS} )
```

The application CMakeLists looks like

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc highgui)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${SUBPROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} MyLib )
```

That was all correct and I always thought that's the way to do it but now with this DSO stuff I just cannot get it to work anymore.

If relevant, I tried with CMake 2.8.7 and 2.8.10, and g++ 4.7.2 and 4.8, all produce the same errors.

Comment: I don't remember whether the order of libraries matter in CMake (i.e. does it feed them in proper order to GCC), but it surely matters for GCC itself. Maybe you should put `MyLib` before `${OpenCV_LIBS}`?

Comment: Oh man you gotta be kidding me... when MyLib depends on ${OpenCV_LIBS}, it has to go BEFORE it on the cmdline? That's very unintuitive for me, my thinking is, first you have to link against ${OpenCV_LIBS} (then it's "defined"), then link to MyLib that depends on ${OpenCV_LIBS} and which is able to find it now...
But actually you're right and I got that wrong ever since I've been using gcc... If you formulate that as an answer, I'll accept... :-) Thanks, so stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is very sensible to the order in which you specify libraries during the linking stage. For example, if `libA.a` depends on `libB.a` and an executable `App` depends on both, then you'd have to invoke linker in the following way:

```
gcc main.o object1.o ... object2.o -lA -lB -o App
```

**NOTE:** Pay attention to the fact that although `A` depends on `B`, still `A` goes before `B`. As a conclusion, *the most independent artifact* should be linked the last one. Sure that's counterintuitive in some sense, but try to treat it in the same way as the `const` qualifier is applied in C++. `:)`

Comment: Seems like that before this linking-behaviour change linked above, it didn't matter in my case (apart from being incorrect), but now the linker got more pedantic and it does matter.
Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @Ela782: But probably there is a better solution. Build system like CMake is all about abstracting away from the compiler and platform. Therefore, in general, it is discouraged to modify `CMakeLists` to fit a particular compiler. It's better to add `target_link_libraries(MyLib ${OpenCV_LIBS})` into `CMakeLists` corresponding to `MyLib`. This way you not only explicitly define dependencies of your artifacts, which is very good for readability, but you also employ the dependency tracking system of CMake. In other words, let CMake to handle link order for you by cleverly helping it to do so.

Comment: Okay, but I always thought that what you propose is bad practice, and good practice is to only let the application do the final linking. Is that not true anymore or was it ever? I informed myself about a year ago and I read that recommendation on several homepages (also on SO I suppose).

Comment: The linkage will still be final. What I propose is actually a higher-level technique since you are using CMake. So this is not about linking multiple times, but rather about instructing CMake on how the dependency graph looks like, so that the final linkage is done in the right order. Moreover, you cannot break anything this way or introduce redundant linking because static libraries depending on each other are linked together only when they are linked into a final executable or dynamic library and never before, i.e. they are just archives of `*.o` files.

Answer (score 1):

Does OpenCV_LIBS contains -lopencv_imgproc? 
  If not, try to add manually -lopencv_imgproc the link command line (run make V=1)
    If it works added it to TARGET_LINK

Comment: Yes of course it contains it, here's the full command of the linking of the app that fails:
`/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/myApp.dir/myApp.cpp.o  -o myApp  -L/home/user/MCR/v81/bin/glnxa64 -rdynamic -lboost_program_options-mt -lmx -lmat -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core ../MyLib/MyLib.a -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/MCR/v81/bin/glnxa64`

Comment: Thanks I had the same problem and that include fixed it!